# React: componentWillRecieveProps is one step behind the parent state at all times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So the user makes changes to the state through an input element with this function:

```
handleCardChange = (event, style) => {
let updated = event.target.value;
this.setState(previousState => ({
  styling: {
    ...previousState.styling,
    styling: {
      ...previousState.styling.styling,
      card: {
        ...previousState.styling.styling.card,
        height: updated
      }
    }
  }
}))
```

}

This updates the state fine, for example if the user puts "600px" in the field then the state will be 600px. Since the state has changed, I want to trigger a re-render of my child component since it uses its props.

I used a componentWillReceiveProps() for this like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("componentWillRecieveProps: ", this.props.styling.styling.card.height);
    this.state = {
        styling: this.props.styling.styling
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the child is behind the parent by one character at all times.
So if parents height is 600px, the childs value is 600p and I need to add another character in the input for the child to update.

Is there any way to fix this and make sure the child component will keep up to date with the parents current state?

Comment: It's definitely an anti-pattern to set state via `this.state = { 
... }`, you should always set state using `this.setState`.

Comment: how do you call "handleCardChange" ? You need to use onKeyUp not onKeyDown

Comment: This question really needs an [mcve].